# is it possible to access data on an external storage device through the iPhones lightning connector outlet

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, memory

If someone were to somehow connect a SD card or usb storage device
(like this one http://www.macworld.com/article/2036911/review-i-flashdrive-hd-a-flash-drive-for-ipads-iphones-and-laptops.html)
 through the iPhone/ipads lightning connecter outlet, is it possible to read/write data onto the external device (maybe save images/videos from the iPhone).
what framework or api should I use.
I would appreciate if someone points me in the right direction